# Next JS cors issue after adding domain name

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a Next.js app hosted on Vercel at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), which needs to communicate with a backend hosted on the same server i.e. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). When I am trying to hit any API I am getting cors error, although I have added the cors configuration in the next.config.js file.

```
      async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'https://example.com/:path*',
          },
        ]
      },
```

I want to hit api and fetch the data and also want to know is there anything in setting cors for my project.